# Error when using else if in sql trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am not sure whats wrong with my code.

```
 delimiter $$
 CREATE TRIGGER updateRestaurantAtributes 
 AFTER UPDATE ON fields_data
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF (NEW.fieldid = 1) THEN
    UPDATE restaurants
    SET address1 = NEW.data_txt 
    Where rid = NEW.itemid;
 ELSE IF (NEW.fieldid = 2) THEN
    UPDATE restaurants
    SET address2 = NEW.data_txt 
    Where rid = NEW.itemid;
 END IF;
END$$
```

The above version does not work. It says syntax error near "END"(Last line). But the something works when I use

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateRestaurantAtributes 
AFTER UPDATE ON fields_data
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.fieldid = 1) THEN
    UPDATE restaurants
    SET address1 = NEW.data_txt 
    Where rid = NEW.itemid;
END IF;
IF (NEW.fieldid = 2) THEN
    UPDATE restaurants
    SET address2 = NEW.data_txt 
    Where rid = NEW.itemid;
END IF;
END$$
```

I am not sure why. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Instead of `ELSE IF`, [MySQL's syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html) uses `ELSEIF` (without the space).

```
 delimiter $$
 CREATE TRIGGER updateRestaurantAtributes 
 AFTER UPDATE ON fields_data
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF (NEW.fieldid = 1) THEN
    UPDATE restaurants
    SET address1 = NEW.data_txt 
    Where rid = NEW.itemid;
 ELSEIF (NEW.fieldid = 2) THEN
    UPDATE restaurants
    SET address2 = NEW.data_txt 
    Where rid = NEW.itemid;
 END IF;
END$$
```

Although you might be able to make it work with the space in `ELSE IF` by adding an additional `END IF`. By using the space, you effectively initiate a second `IF` statement, which must be closed independently of the first outer `IF` statement.

```
/* Might work */
delimiter $$
 CREATE TRIGGER updateRestaurantAtributes 
 AFTER UPDATE ON fields_data
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF (NEW.fieldid = 1) THEN
    UPDATE restaurants
    SET address1 = NEW.data_txt 
    Where rid = NEW.itemid;
 /* Opens a seconds IF block which must be closed */
 ELSE IF (NEW.fieldid = 2) THEN
    UPDATE restaurants
    SET address2 = NEW.data_txt 
    Where rid = NEW.itemid;
  /* Close inner IF block */
  END IF;
 END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: Adding link for syntax :-) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html

Comment: @AdrianCornish Thanks it's already in there, linked to the words "MySQL's syntax"

Comment: My apologies - I did not click the link

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql Workbench 8.0 click settings icon bedside the table and there you will find trigger tab. Create Trigger according to your requirement, following if-else syntax will work perfectly

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `users_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

 IF (NEW.status_active = 1) THEN
    UPDATE broadcast_status SET `type` = 0, `status` = 0 WHERE user_id = NEW.id;

 ELSE 
        IF (NEW.status_active = 2) THEN
            UPDATE broadcast_status SET `type` = 0, `status` = 2 WHERE user_id = NEW.id;
        ELSE 
            UPDATE broadcast_status SET `type` = 0, `status` = 1 WHERE user_id = NEW.id;
        END IF;
 END IF;

END
```